# Compile renderscript error "llvm-rs-cc finished with non-zero exit value 127"

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to build a renderscript in Android studio, but I got the following error:

```
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/yoss/Android/Sdk/build-tools/28.0.3/llvm-rs-cc'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

I thought it was a compilation error, so I removed the code lines one by one, but I kept getting the error even when the file was empty. I searched on this site and other internet sites, all the similar issues I found pointed to problems in old versions of the Android tools, but I upgraded to the latest version and the error is still the same. The current configuration is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28
        renderscriptTargetApi 23
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
}
```

These are the tools and SDK tools I have in my Android Studio:

[image: Installed Android Tools]

[image: Installed Android SDK Tools]

Does anyone have any idea about what might be the cause?

Edit:
I forgot to add a detail, my OS is Linux, openSUSE Leap 15.0 x86_64

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue. I tried to execute the command manually and I saw a library error, it was missing libncurses.so.5
Since on my machine I have libncurses version 6 first I tried to fix the issue by creating two symbolic links to libncursesw.so.6.1, but it didn't work. Then I installed  libncurses version 5 alongside version 6 and it worked.

Comment: Thank you! One can just run `llvm-rs-cc` without arguments to see the error message about the missing library. I faced it on Manjaro (read Arch) distribution, where it was solved by `yay -S ncurses5-compat-libs` (install from AUR).

Comment: For Fedora 32: "sudo dnf install ncurses-compat-libs" (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51698081/435519 and confirmed as a fix by me with my install).

Comment: @Mikolasan I noticed with time that running llvm-rs-cc without arguments can help solve a smaller range of issues. Unfortunately with my Android studio setup there is no feedback from the renderscript compilation and I have to execute the entire command I get from the error trace just to find compilation errors.