# arm-none-eabi-gdb: " error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5" - Fedora

Tags: arm, gdb, gnu, fedora

The arm-none-eabi-* packages for Fedora 36 do not provide `arm-none-eabi-gdb`. So I downloaded the [pre-compiled binaries for Linux](https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm) directly from Arm. When I try to run `arm-none-eabi-gdb`, I get the following error message.

```
$ ./arm-none-eabi-gdb
./arm-none-eabi-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51698081/863879) to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698044/libncurses-so-5-cannot-open-shared-library-fedora), the solution is to install the `ncurses-compat-libs` package.

```
$ sudo dnf install ncurses-compat-libs
```

There are [other solutions](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/08/arm-toolchain-ubuntu-19-04-black-magic-probe/) out there in the wild that suggest doing something like creating symbolic links to the newer `.so` files, but I think installing the compatibility library is the preferred approach.

Comment: *ncurses-compat-libs* not found. No more available this submodule in dnf. Take a look at [My Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964313/12183952)